# How to paste text without font/style formatting on macOS?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, clipboard

How do I paste text on the clipboard into a text field without the font/style formatting? That is, I want to paste it as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Press **Command-Option-Shift-V** to paste text as plain text without formatting on macOS. This does not change the contents of the clipboard, so pressing Command-V will still paste the text with font/style formatting applied.